# Как заставить рисовать picturebox, то что выбрано в checkListBox C#

Tags: c#, winforms

У меня есть `checkListBox`, в нём есть названия фигур. Мне нужно, когда выбрано какое-то значение(я), рисовать это на `picturebox`.

Как такое же реализовать для `checkListBox`?

```
switch (comboBox1.SelectedIndex)
            {
                // Точки 
                case 0:
                    brush.Color = pen.Color;
                    gfx.FillRectangle (brush, x, y, 1, 1);
                    break;

                // Линии
                case 1:
                    gfx.DrawLine (pen, x, y, x1, y1);              
                    break;

                // Прямоугольники
                case 2:
                    gfx.FillRectangle (brush, x, y, Width, Height);
                    gfx.DrawRectangle (pen, x, y, Width, Height);
                    break;
                // Эллипс 
                case 3:
                    gfx.FillEllipse (brush, x, y, Width, Height);
                    gfx.DrawEllipse (pen, x, y, Width, Height);
                    break;
                // Текст 
                case 4:
                    brush.Color = pen.Color;
                    gfx.DrawString ("Hello", font, brush, x, y);
                    break;
            }
```

Comment: WinForms или WPF? метка faq лишняя

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можно по определенному событию (нажатие кнопки "Нарисовать" или при изменении одного из элементов checkListBox) проходится по всем элементам и дорисовывать необходимый элемент:

```
...
for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
    if (checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(i))
        draw(checkedListBox1.Items[i].ToString());
...

void draw(string item)
{
    switch (item)
    {
        case "0": 
            //добавить к рисунку точку
        break;
        case "1": 
            //добавить к рисунку линию
        break;
        ...
    }
}
...
```

В строку переводить необязательно.