# Рисование примитивов в c#

Tags: c#, winforms, рисование

Недавно начал изучать c#, и не могу сделать вот такое задание: Создать программу которая позволяет рисовать в формате графических примитив: окружность, отрезок, прямоугольник, сектор, текст, эллипс, и закрашенный сектор. Выбор того или иного графического примитива осуществляется с помощью элемента управления listbox. Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Э-э-э... Вам прямо сюда программу выложить?

Comment: Так а в чём вопрос? Что вы уже попробовали, что не получилось?

Comment: @Igor, Нет, хотя бы подскзать, как сделать. Немного не понимаю просто, сижу читаю документацию

Comment: @UladzimirPalekh, пока толком ничего, только создал форму с кнопочками и pucturebox'ом.

Comment: @UladzimirPalekh, пробовал это : https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-create-graphics-objects-for-drawing 
Затем это: 
https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-draw-an-outlined-shape
Еще вот это:
https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-draw-text-on-a-windows-form

Comment: Не могу понять, как сделать так, что бы я в listbox'e выбрал нужный элемент, затем нажал кнопку и нарисовалась та фигура, которая написана в listbox. Саму связь не знаю как сделать.

Comment: А может вам еще рано для такого и стоит пойти с самого начала? Узнать сам c#, понять как работают классы, методы, создавать объекты, узнайте что такое ООП и тогда я на 99% уверен, что подобных вопросов у вас не будет. Или вы хотите каждый свой путь обучения описывать здесь в мольбе о том, чтобы кто то помог? Если да, то это плохо... Тогда предоставьте нам ваши попытки реализовать это и опишите конкретно что именно у вас не получилось. Старайтесь сделать сами, мой вам совет!

Comment: Нужно начать с того, что одного типа фигуры недостаточно. Они имеют размеры и положение, причём для разных фигур задаются разные параметры. Вам нужно подумать, как их задать (возможно, хватит случайных значений). Что же касается реализации, то при нажатии на кнопку "Рисовать" проверяйте, какой элемент выбран в ```ListBox``` и в зависимости от него вызывайте необходимую функцию типа ```DrawLine```.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, Мне просто дали задание, которое необходимо выполнить. Я бы с радостью начал все учить с нуля, но к сожалению, нет времени. Я и стараюсь сделать сам, сейчас у меня ступор, что я не знаю как реализовать, что бы когда я из listbox'a выбрал нужный мне элемент, и нажал на кнопку, он появился на picturebox'e.

Comment: @UladzimirPalekh, Я именно и не знаю, как сделать проверку.

Comment: У объекта типа ```ListBox``` есть свойство ```SelectedItem```. Используйте его, чтобы получить выбранный элемент.

Comment: Не понял немного, все равно. Добавил вот это: 
_foreach (string s in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.OfType<string>())_
Текст выделенной переменной он хранит в s, что дальше-не знаю. @UladzimirPalekh

Comment: @Uporaba, а дальше нужно взять книжку по C# и разобраться с управляющими конструкциями типа ```switch``` и ```if```.

Comment: @UladzimirPalekh, if знаю, switch тоже в принципе. Нашел [статью](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/642985/Как-заставить-рисовать-picturebox-то-что-выбрано-в-checklistbox-c) похожую под мой случай, не подскажите, как под listbox переделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Только лишь для затравки...

Начнем с абстракции

```
public enum FigureType
{
    Circle,
    Line,
    Rectangle,
    Sector,
    Text,
    Ellipse,
    ShadedSector
}

interface IFigure
{
    FigureType Type { get; }
    string Name { get; }
    Point FirstPoint { get; set; }
    Point SecondPoint { get; set; }
}
```

Далее реализуем интерфейс так

```
class Figure : IFigure
{
    //ctor
    public Figure(FigureType figureType, string name)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)) throw new ArgumentException(nameof(name));

        Type = figureType;
        Name = name;
    }

    public FigureType Type { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public Point FirstPoint { get; set; }
    public Point SecondPoint { get; set; }
}
```

Сама форма такая

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private IFigure _selectedFigure;
    private bool _IsDrawing;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        SetDataToListBox();

        _listBoxFigures.SelectedIndexChanged += ListBoxFigures_SelectedChanged;
        _panelCanvas.MouseDown += PanelCanvas_MouseDown;
        _panelCanvas.MouseUp += PanelCanvas_MouseUp;
        _panelCanvas.Paint += PanelCanvas_Paint;

        this.CenterToScreen();
        this.Text = "Примерчик";
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Заполнение списка
    /// </summary>
    private void SetDataToListBox()
    {
        _listBoxFigures.DataSource = new List<IFigure>
        {
            new Figure(FigureType.Line, "Отрезок"),
            new Figure(FigureType.Rectangle, "Прямоугольник"),
            new Figure(FigureType.Circle, "Окружность"),
        };
        _listBoxFigures.DisplayMember = nameof(IFigure.Name);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Обработка события выбора в списке
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void ListBoxFigures_SelectedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_listBoxFigures.SelectedItem == null) return;

        _selectedFigure = _listBoxFigures.SelectedItem as IFigure;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Обработка события нажатия левой кнопки мыши на Панели
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void PanelCanvas_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_selectedFigure == null) return;

        _selectedFigure.FirstPoint = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Обработка события отпускания кнопки мыши на Панели
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void PanelCanvas_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_selectedFigure == null) return;

        _selectedFigure.SecondPoint = new Point(e.X, e.Y);

        _IsDrawing = true;
        _panelCanvas.Refresh();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Обработка события перерисовки Панели
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void PanelCanvas_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!_IsDrawing) return;

        switch (_selectedFigure.Type)
        {
            case FigureType.Circle:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            case FigureType.Line:
                DrawLine(e.Graphics);
                break;
            case FigureType.Rectangle:
                DrawRectangle(e.Graphics);
                break;
            case FigureType.Sector:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            case FigureType.Text:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            case FigureType.Ellipse:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            case FigureType.ShadedSector:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        _IsDrawing = false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Рисование Прямоугольника
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="graphics"></param>
    private void DrawRectangle(Graphics graphics)
    {
        var width = _selectedFigure.SecondPoint.X - _selectedFigure.FirstPoint.X;
        var height = _selectedFigure.SecondPoint.Y - _selectedFigure.FirstPoint.Y;

        var rectangle =
            new Rectangle(_selectedFigure.FirstPoint.X, _selectedFigure.FirstPoint.Y, width, height);
        Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 5);
        graphics.DrawRectangle(blackPen, rectangle);
        blackPen.Dispose();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Рисование Линии
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="graphics"></param>
    private void DrawLine(Graphics graphics)
    {
        Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 5);
        graphics.DrawLine(blackPen, _selectedFigure.FirstPoint, _selectedFigure.SecondPoint);
        blackPen.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Работает это так

[image: пример работы]

Весь пример можно скачать [здесь](https://yadi.sk/d/EElAmF5HOKpNyQ)

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Comment: Пожалуйста.  еще немного символов

Comment: Я так понимаю, остальные элементы из списка я сам добавить должен? Хотя,так даже лучше, я немного разберусь как это работает. Еще раз спасибо.

Comment: Ну, я же написал, что для затравки....

Comment: Понял, там с кругом пробелмсы какие-то

Comment: С кругом никаких проблем нет. Реализацию я не сделал. Вы уж сами, пожалуйста, разберитесь с кодом, и напишите сами.

Comment: Просто ошибку выбивает, ну ладно. Еще раз спасибо!

Comment: Ошибку выдает, потому что стоит вызов исключения вместо вызова нужного метода, который вы должны уже сами написать по аналогии с методами рисования линии и окружности.

Comment: Вроде со всем почти разобрался, только текст почему-то вертикально стоит, это из-за координат может быть? И еще я не могу несколько раз его напечатать, только один. Делал все по официальной документации.

Comment: Разобрался пока только как текст перевернуть.

Comment: Добавил все, кроме сектора. Не могу понять как нарисовать. Сектор-это же какая-то часть от фигуры, как мне это реализовать?

Comment: @Uporaba, используйте ```DrawPie``` для рисования сектора.

Comment: @UladzimirPalekh, Я уже все сделал, спасибо! Можете пояснить за вот это:  public enum FigureType; class Figure : IFigure. Второе я так понимаю класс IFigure, а первое что?

Comment: `enum` - перечисление, `IFigure` - интерфейс, `Figure` - класс реализующий этот интерфейс. В принципе, можно было обойтись без интерфейса, но начинать проектирование программы всегда нужно с абстракций, т.е. с интерфейсов и абстрактных классов.